# Manejo de errores en Laravel

Tags: laravel-5

quisiera saber como manejar mensajes personalizados en los errores. Por ahora tengo esto en app/Exceptions/Handler.php

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{    
    return response()->view('errors.error', ['error_message' => $e->getMessage()], 500);

}
```

Y en el archivo **error.blade.php** ubicado en la carpeta **errors** simplemente tengo una vista personalizada para que salga el mensaje de algún color pero quisiera saber si es posible que por cada tipo de error pueda enviar un mensaje diferente al usuario en pantalla.

Comment: ¿A qué tipo de errores te refieres? digamos mostrar una vista para 404 y otra para 503?

Comment: A cualquier error en general, ya sea una llave fornánea, un error de sintaxis.. o tal como lo dices, uno para 404, otro para 503 pero no con los mensajes que se ve por defecto sino con uno personalizado por el desarrollador

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola perdón por no poder comentar, pero todavía no puedo.

Si es posible y todo está explicado aquí:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation

Por ejemplo para validar campos, esto ya te lo debes saber:

```
'custom' => [
    'email' => [
        'required' => 'Necesitamos el e-mail chiquilin!!',
    ],
],
```

O por ejemplo una validación personalizada como:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#custom-validation-rules

```
public function boot()
{
    Validator::extend('validame', function($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
        if($value < 100){
           return "Estás más que reprobado";
        }
        return "aprobado"
    });
}
```

A las cuales también puedes agregar mensajes de errores personalizados :D